# Choice of Java-based Key-value store for advanced queries

Tags: key-value-store, nosql

I am looking for a suitable distributed key-value store that would fulfil the following:
 - be written in Java,
 - be fully distributed (balanced distribution of the values among the workers, replication, fast local key-value store on the workers),
 - allow me to run queries for a "set of keys" and let me modify the code on individual workers to further process (filter) the locally retrieved keys and return its own answer.

I considered project Voldemort promissing but it seems that it strictly supports only single key-value queries and the modification would be very complicated. Does anybody has any tip, please?

Comment: The definition of a key/value store is usually that it buys better performance by omitting the ability for any advanced queries. What you really seem to be looking for is a proper database.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an "answer" as such as this is a broad topic, but we use Apache Cassandra and are quite 
happy with it. And I like the Apache backing (licensing, recognition, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have found the solution - Infinispan is a distributed K-V store that has a "Distributed Execution Framework", which allows to execute a code on relevant workers (and merge the results): http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_distributed_execution_framework

Thanks everyone